# @font-face style google-apps-script

Tags: css, google-apps-script

I have this as style used in google app script webapp where we setup style sheet also as html page (with style tags included) and include them in main html page.   It uses default font instead of snippet below.

```
@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/s/g2lk505elj1aamj/MISTV___.TTF')
}

div.happy {
  font-family: 'myFirstFont';
}
```

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font-faces are not allowed with HTMLService and Caja Sanitization, ran into the same problem last week myself.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-caja-discuss/WhqEZqfFn6g